# sql query for specific date interval

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database

```
id   name         mydate                   
1     co        2011-02-10 07:25:02  
2     Carl      2011-02-10 07:26:02
.
.
.
10000   Caroline  2011-02-18 22:44:08
```

I have a database like that, I wanna search through for a specified interval such as (1 hour). For instance, I want to see the records between 07 AM and 08 AM among the all records for all days. And then, I will use each day's 7 AM and 8 AM for further process. How can I do that in C#?

Comment: Is it inclusive or exclusive? Is 7:00AM and 8:00AM included in the range 07AM-08AM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT [mydate] 
    FROM [table] 
    WHERE DATEPART(hh,[mydate]) >= 6 
        AND DATEPART(hh,[mydate]) <= 8 
    Order by DATEPART(hh,[mydate])
```

Comment: Yes. And it will select all records in that hour. not on one specific day.

Comment: A function of SQL Server you can use in queries

Comment: When I try this,,,, string query = "SELECT date FROM  people WHERE DATEPART(hh,[mydate]) >= 6 AND DATEPART(hh,[mydate]) <= 8 Order by DATEPART(hh,[mydate])";      I get that error "No value given for one or more required parameters."

Answer (score 2):

You can use the BETWEEN keyword.

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE mydate between '1/1/56 07:00:00' and '12/31/57 08:00:00'
```

This is not C# specific. If your using LINQ it something like this:

```
from mt in ctx.MyTable where mydate >= datestart and mydate <= stopdate select mt
```

In this case ctx is the context, startdate the lower date and stopdate the higher and.

If you want to read the result using ADO.NET:

```
var cn = new SqlConnection("paste your code here");

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(); 
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM A WHERE mydate between '1/1/56 07:00:00' and '12/31/57 08:00:00'";
cmd.Connection = cn;

try
{
    cn.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // up to you
    }
    reader.Close();
}
finally
{
    cn.Close();
}
```

Comment: I wanna do it programmatically, I may not know the exact date, I just consider each day's  7 am and 8 am,

Comment: Then you need to build your sql dynamically. Not a SQL question. Or you might use a procedure.

Comment: What do you mean procedure , Could you please explain it bit ?

Comment: See http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/a/storedprocedure.htm for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE DATEPART(hh, mydate) = @start
OR (DATEPART(hh, mydate) = @end AND DATEPART(mi, mydate) = 0)
ORDER BY mydate
```

`DATEPART` is a SQL function that gets the specified portion of the date given the date value.
In the sql script above, @start and @end are the integer values of the starting hours, in the case of 7AM to 8AM, @start = 7 and @end = 8.

Essentially, you're getting all records from your table that has a date with the hour component equal to 7 or a date with the hour component equal to 8 and with the minute component equal to 0. This should get all records between 7:00 AM to 8:00 AM inclusive.

Comment: I am getting error at that line -> data_adaptor.Fill(dt); error says "No value given for one or more required parameters."

Comment: and If I search through in excel file, can I use DATEPART command,too ?

Comment: How exactly are you entering the SQL script? Could you post your code? You must add parameter values for `@start` and `@end`. As for EXCEL, no, but there should be an equivalent function.

Comment: I tried like that   string query = "SELECT id,name FROM people WHERE DATEPART(hh, mydate) = @start OR (DATEPART(hh, mydate) = at end AND DATEPART(mi, mydate) = 0) ORDER BY mydate";

Comment: What is equivalent function , if I search through an excel file  instead database file in C# ?

Comment: And where do you use the `query`? As for your Excel file question, you may want to post another question so you can have better answers :)

Comment: I mean like that  string query = "select id,date from [Sheet1$]";

Comment: What I mean is, after you gave `query` the value, what do you do next? Add to a SqlCommand object? The code for that is necessary so we can fix the "No value given for one or more required parameters" error.

For Excel, you will have a better chance of getting an answer if you post another question, since this question is about SQL. I'm not too fond of using Excel in C# myself.